# Need help converting wildcard CRT to PFX for use with Windows Azure

Tags: iis-7, ssl, azure, ssl-certificate

I need help preparing a wildcard SSL certificate purchased from NetworkSolutions. I called their tech support, and Jason told me "I am unfamiliar with Windows, just google it...".

Here is what I have done:

1. Started IIS 7 Manager
2. Went to "Server Certificates" and clicked "Complete Certificate Request"
3. Entered the path for the STAR.DOMAIN.COM.crt file I downloaded from network solutions, along with a friendly name.
4. Clicked OK

When I do this, the cert appears in the Server Certificates list. However, there is no "Export" link... only View, Renew, and Remove. Also, when I leave the Server Certificates screen and come back, it is no longer there.

This same process works with our old single-domain SSL cert which expires in 2 weeks. When I complete a certificate request for it, it appears and stays in the Server Certificates section, and can be exported to PFX.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

find a different company.  a place with a support staff telling you to 'just google it' is a company that does not deserve your business.

also, [this link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CIMBEBYwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.digicert.com%2Fssl-support%2Fpfx-import-export-iis-7.htm&ei=NX-qT774KpP06AHyp6zEBA&usg=AFQjCNHWacpOkZcvdNEWtQVQul7EpReZZg&sig2=HPACOAQw9c9_JiX2aLJDJQ) might be able to help you.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe it's because they didn't ask me for a CSR when I purchased it (did it over phone). I just created a new CSR and reissued through their web site. Should be getting new certs in about an hour, +1 for the link, thanks.

Comment: Still though, if you have a direct contact for them (an account manager or someone NOT in support) i would tell them that this has made you question your choice in doing business with them.  That is a level of unprofessionalism that's disgusting.  It is the support person's JOB to do the googleing, or to pass the call on to someone who knows more.